# Can constructors perform operations like a method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, constructor

I'm doing a homework and I'm really stuck with this problem. We are told to create a constructor that takes in a string argument, turns it into lower case, and splits it into separate words.And then indexes the document(as in a search engine).This assignment is designed to let us know a bit about how search engines work.

I have always used methods to perform such operations but now the question is asking to do that in a `constructor`. I tried several times and it's not working. The assignment also asks to store the distinct words (after I split them in the `constructor`) in an array called "Terms", which also stores the frequencies of the words. Another portion of the question is asking to create a method `indexContent`to populate the terms array of `proper` size.

I hope three information somehow relate but I have no idea. I need help, especially with creating such `constructor` as I mentioned. I didn't even know `constructors` can perform `method` like operations. I thought `constructors` are created to instantiate objects and `methods` are used to call and perform operations. Please someone explain.

Comment: One word `Yes`. But don't have return type.

Comment: I also need to use those split and lower case words to perform some other operations like count unique words, frequencies, print in a table; how do I invoke methods to stuff that happened inside constructor.Really not making any sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. `Constructor` can do all the things as a method. In fact, constructor is a method that **implicit** return its class type.

For example:

```
// constructor in fact is return its class type
People a = new People("StackoverFlow");
```

There are some restrictions in `constructor`, for example you must call parent's constructor in some situations, but not method.

For example:

```
class Parent {
   public Parent(String parentName) {}
}

class Child extends Parent {
   public Child(String name) {
      // must call parent constructor. unlike normal method
      super(name);
      // do some other fancy stuffs here
   }
}
```

In your assignment, Psuedocode will be:

```
class SearchEngine {
    // keyword after turn into lower
    private String lowerKeyword;

    // words is splitted by above keyword
    private String[] words;

    public SearchEngine(String keyword) {
        process(keyword);
    }

    private void process(String keyword) {
       // convert keyword to lower case and assign to lowerKeywords
       // convert keyword to separate words and assign to array words
       // index document
    }

    // or you can process your code directly in constructor
    public SearchEngine(String keyword, String someOtherParameter) {
       // convert keyword to lower case and assign to lowerKeywords
       // convert keyword to separate words and assign to array words
       // index document
    }
}
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: What do you mean by process(keyword) ? All the operations are still done in the process void method ,but the question is asking to do all that in constructor.I'm really confused.

Comment: @RafsanMobasher I have edited my answer. I have added another constructor demo. As you see, in constructor, you can call other method or you can put **anything** in that constructor. Nevertheless I prefer first constructor. It makes your code cleaner.

Comment: @hqt `constructor is a method that implicit return its class type.` Another way to see it is that a constructor is a method that explicitly returns its class type but does not have a name ;) But that is rather philosophical I guess ^^

Comment: As far as the Java Language Spec is concerned, a constructor is not a method.  And that makes sense - it differs in at least a few ways (e.g. requirements around calling `super`, no return type, can't be invoked directly, etc.).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yeah. obvious, we can not say `constructor **IS** a method`. If we say: **LIKE** a method will be more appropriate. :) This just help original poster sees that there are really no fancy between constructor and method.